# \to or \longrightarrow and \mapsto or \longrightarrow in functions?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath

I'm typing up a research project and I am not sure which ones I should use when I'm defining functions. I personally prefer `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto` but I see a lot of people use `\to` and `\mapsto`. What in your opinion looks more 'presentable'?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this isn't really a tex question, but a question of notation, which would be more appropriate on a math forum.  that said, i suggest you refer to a published source that you think looks "professional" and follow its lead.

Comment: In my opinion `\to` (which is a shorthand for `\rightarrow`) and `\mapsto` suffice.